# English grammar : We call such ~ ~

Tags: grammar

I was studying English in my school.

Today's grammar was about the concept - call(name) such (objective) (noun)

Here are some examples;

> We call such people dancers.

> People call such music hip-hop.

However, another example said:

> We call such ***a dance*** flamenco.

Is this grammatically correct?

I am studying in a country which doesn't use English as a home language
so I honestly don't trust the curriculum they have here.

Please tell me how this call such ~ works.
Is singular possible?

Comment: "We call such a dance flamengo." is grammatically correct.  [Aside: in English we have "flamenco", not "flamengo".]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is nothing special about *call such*:

- We label such people dancers
- We name such people dancers
- We term such people dancers
- We dub such people dancers [rare]

*Label, name, term* and *dub* are all verbs of naming (with roughly the same meaning), and they don't have anything special to do with the *such*. A less formal equivalent of *such x* is *x like that*, or *that kind of x*:

- We call people like that dancers
- We call that kind of person a dancer

*Such a dance* is indeed correct for the singular form. These are just the indefinite singular/plural forms:

- A dancer dances
- Dancers dance
- Such a dancer dances well
- Such dancers dance well

Comment: So what you mean is
'We call such a music k-pop'  is correct?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. The reason is that 'music' is an uncountable noun. With uncountable nouns there is no indefinite article, so you say "We call such music..."

Comment: "Dancers" is a noun.

Comment: @BillJ ...yes, and?

Comment: You said they were verbs of naming. Verb doesn't come into it.

Comment: @BillJ I said "these are all verbs of naming" after four example sentences.  Not sure why you picked out "dancers" in particular from those sentences. But I can make it even clearer by replacing "these" with the verbs themselves, which I shall now do.

Comment: I thought you were talking about "dancers". I can now see that you're talking about "label", "name" etc. The important thing is that "such people" is an NP functioning as object, and "dancers" is objective PC.

Comment: Yes, I agree. If you look at the original question, my jumping-off point was to avoid a misunderstanding on the part of the OP who seemed to think that "call such ~" was a special set phrase.